# how can I sum a column in a join query with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I would like to join two tables with user_id as the common field and sum 2 fields in table 2. Among many attempts, a query that works is:

```
   data = db.session.query(Subscription.units, Subscription.subscription, Subscription.user_id, func.sum(Subscription.units).label('units'), func.sum(Subscription.subscription).label('sub')).filter(user_id==2).group_by(Subscription.user_id, Subscription.units, Subscription.subscription)
```

When I attempt to display this in the template with the following code:

```
{% for item in data %}
<div>
You have invested <span class="green"> Euro  {{ item.sub }} </span> and you own <span class="blue"> {{ item.units }} </span> shares.
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Frustratingly and humorously it iterates over all the entries for this user_id and prints it all out as follows:

```
You have invested Euro 0.0 and you own 0.0 shares.
You have invested Euro 5000.0 and you own 5.0 shares.
You have invested Euro 3000.0 and you own 2.63 shares.
You have invested Euro 0.0 and you own 0.0 shares.
```

The summing is not taking place, I want just one line in the view which says:

```
You have invested Euro 8000.0 and you own 7.63 shares.
```

is the error being caused by a faulty query or by incorrect loop in the template?

Comment: Your example code and the code in the error do not match. Your errors are of the kind that you should refresh your [Python basics](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) – `something.(other.stuff)` is a syntax error for example. Move selections to the select list, or in other words to `db.session.query()` call.

Comment: Check out this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471724/how-to-use-sum-and-count-in-a-joined-query-on-sqlalchemy-models

Comment: thanks. I already did and I cannot successfully apply it to my use case.

Comment: thank Ilja, I understand your comment now. Here is the correct code:
data = db.session.query(User.firstname, Subscription.units, Subscription.subscription, func.sum(Subscription.units).label('total_units'), func.sum(Subscription.subscription).label('total_sub')).filter(User.id==1).join(Subscription, User.id==Subscription.user_id).group_by(User.firstname, Subscription.units, Subscription.subscription).all()

Comment: I have revised my question.

Comment: I have now resolved this. I will provide the answer when the system allows me to "answer my own question."